# How do you store three different objects in a list array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I need to create a list array in java that can hold three different objects (Surname, forename, Result) and was wondering how to do that

Comment: (assuming java) A better approach will probably be to create a `class` for it, with the fields `surname` `forname` and `result`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best and also Object Oriented approach is to Create a class with surname, forename and result as attributes(instance variables) like below:

```
class Student{
private String surname;
private String forename;
private String result;
public Details(String surname, String forename, String res){
   //initialize properties here
  }
}
```

now, create a List which only accepts `Student` Object.

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
list.add(new Student("surname", "forname", "pass"));
```